# How to append to list in loop without getting multiple list outputs

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a dataset with 60 levels and I'm trying to get the mean for each level. For example, I want the mean for all the diameters for level 1, mean of diameters for level 2, etc. My end goal is to have this in a dataframe with the levels as column headers and the mean diameter as the first row. For now, I'm just trying to get a function to output a list of the mean diameters by level.

The following code does this, but it gives me 60 lists that step up from 1 mean to 60, instead of 1 list with 60 means:

```
def diameter(df):
    mean_diameter = []
    for z in range(0,61):
        d = df.loc[(df['zoom']==z+1, 'diameter')].mean()
        mean_diameter.append(d)
        print(mean_diameter)

diameter(df)
```

I'm looking for an output with 60 means...one for each level. If I use `mean_diameter = d` instead of `mean_diameter.append(d)`, I get just the 60 values I need, but obviously it's not in a list format. Help is appreciated.

Comment: can you provide an example of input-output?

Comment: What is the `d` that you append?  Type, shape, etc; Your function should return `mean_diameter`, not print it each time.